# Unable to compare valuesfrom mysql in a prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo, prepared-statement

I can't seem to get this to connect to the database so that I can run my prepared statement. Does anybody have an idea what I've forgotten?

```
private function check_credentials($plain_username, $password)
    {
    global $dbcon;

    $ac = new ac();
    $ac->dbconnect();
    $userid = $dbcon->prepare('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password LIMIT 1');
    $userid->bindParam(':username', $plain_username);
    $userid->bindParam(':password', $password);
    $userid->execute();

    $id = $userid->fetch();
    Return $id;
    }
```

**EDIT:** I changed the SQL query from a SELECT FROM query, to an INSERT INTO query and it worked. WHat the heck is going on?

Comment: What is your `errorInfo()` saying? http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php  You'll need some kind of error handling anyway, don't you think? ... and haven't we had this exchange before earlier today?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound' in E:\PortableApps\xampp\htdocs\SN\AC\ACclass.php:61 Stack trace: #0 E:\PortableApps\xampp\htdocs\SN\AC\ACclass.php(61): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 E:\PortableApps\xampp\htdocs\SN\AC\ACclass.php(34): ac->check_credentials('joe', '94a02c32b6ff629...') #2 E:\PortableApps\xampp\htdocs\SN\UI\UIclass.php(17): ac->authentication() #3 E:\PortableApps\xampp\htdocs\SN\index.php(4): ui->start() #4 {main} thrown in E:\PortableApps\xampp\htdocs\SN\AC\ACclass.php on line 61

Comment: @pekka Same function, different question. Got rid of the other question, cause I realized I was asking the wrong thing, and it was throwing people off

Comment: @Cortopasta I see. Strange. The preparation looks okay, but "no parameters were bound" speaks a pretty clear language. Maybe somebody with more experience in PDO than me can tell you more.

Comment: I don't know what ac() is but, the only thing I see glaringly wrong about this code is that 'Return' should be 'return'.

Comment: Looks like I found a problem SO can't answer :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reformatting your stack backtrace:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound' in E:\PortableApps\xampp\htdocs\SN\AC\ACclass.php:61
Stack trace:
#0 E:\PortableApps\xampp\htdocs\SN\AC\ACclass.php(61): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 E:\PortableApps\xampp\htdocs\SN\AC\ACclass.php(34): ac->check_credentials('joe', '94a02c32b6ff629...')
#2 E:\PortableApps\xampp\htdocs\SN\UI\UIclass.php(17): ac->authentication()
#3 E:\PortableApps\xampp\htdocs\SN\index.php(4): ui->start()
#4 {main} thrown in E:\PortableApps\xampp\htdocs\SN\AC\ACclass.php on line 61
```

Is there any reason you're instantiating a new `ac` object in the check_credentials function? Given that check_credentials is already a method of `ac`, this seems odd. Does `dbconnect` overwrite the global `dbcon`?

Comment: Honestly, I have no reason for it other than I thought that's how it worked. Let me change it and see if it works

Comment: About all I can suggest is var_dump/print_r the $dbcon and $userid after each step, see if anything funky shows up in there.